# How to find out what disposed single?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a simple code for connecting to device and return Single for handle this connection. The device could not response, so there is a timeout operator.

```
fun getDataFromDevice() : Single<DataFromDevice> {
   return Single.create { emmiter ->
      val data = fetchSyncData();
      Timber.d("is emmiter disposed ${emmiter.isDisposed}")
      emitter.onSucces(data);
   }
   .timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

Then in presenter, wen user enter to the screen is called below code:

```
   //...
    getDataFromDevice()
    .subscribeOn(Shcedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidShcedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnDispose { Timber.d("disposed") }
    .subscribe(
      { handleSucces(it) },
      { showError(it) }
     )
    //...
```

So I observe strange behavior: after first field connection every time the **new** Single was disposed quickly. It's very wired situation so I need get info what dispose the single? How get it?

Comment: consider using a `CompositeDisposable` or a `Disposable`

Comment: @StavroXhardha Thx, :) but I want to find what dispose my subscription. I had attached to `CompositeDisposable`  object my subscription but removed it and still something dispose my subscription and I don't know what. I try to figure out what.

Comment: Single gets disposed after it reaches either success or error.